# Ito isometry for different time interval

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Without throwing too much technical details, The Ito isometry says

$$
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\Big(\int^t_0 X_s d W_s\Big) \Big(\int^t_0 X_s d W_s\Big)^T \bigg] = \int^t_0 X_s\,X_s^T ds,
$$

for some suitable Brownian motion $W_t$.

How about in the above two integrals $t$ are not the same? That is,

$$
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\Big(\int^{t_1}_0 X_s d W_s\Big) \Big(\int^{t_2}_0 X_s d W_s\Big)^T \bigg] = ?
$$

Is it equal to $\int^{\mathrm{min}(t_1, t_2)}_0 X_s\,X_s^T ds$? If yes how to prove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your intuition is right here is why, supposing $t_1<t_2$ :

$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\Big(\int^{t_1}_0 X_s d W_s\Big) \Big(\int^{t_2}_0 X_s d W_s\Big)^T \bigg] =\mathbb{E}\bigg[\Big(\int^{t_1}_0 X_s d W_s\Big) \Big(\int^{t_1}_0 X_s d W_s+\int^{t_2}_{t_1} X_s d W_s\Big)^T \bigg]=$$
$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\Big(\int^{t_1}_0 X_s d W_s\Big) \Big(\int^{t_1}_0 X_s d W_s\Big)^T \bigg]+\mathbb{E}\bigg[\Big(\int^{t_1}_0 X_s d W_s\Big) \Big(\int^{t_2}_{t_1} X_s d W_s\Big)^T \bigg]$$

Now observe that the second term is null as the two random variables are independent  as the first integral belongs to $\mathcal{F}_{t_1}$ and the second to $\mathcal{F}_{t_2, t_1}$ that are independent. You are left with the term for which you know the result already.